# Creating a plugin to automatically update either a line, point or polygon to a PostGIS database and turn the geometry into a GeoJSON

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins

I'm trying to create a plugin that once someone updates a geometry in QGIS this will automatically update to the PostGIS table and also convert it to a GeoJSON. I have a popup box for the user to insert  the table that is being updated. Another popup might be handy to check its changing the correct charge in the data with the id of the data.

This is what I have so far:

````
#prompt for table name update
import PyQt5.QtGui
qid = QInputDialog()
title = "Enter table name"
label = "Name: "
mode = QLineEdit.Normal
default = "<table name here>"
text, ok = QInputDialog.getText(qid, title, label, mode, default)#connect to database to update the geometry field


from qgis.core import *
from qgis.core import QgsProject
from PyQt5.QtCore import QFileInfo
from qgis.core import QgsVectorLayer
QgsDataSourceUri
from qgis.utils import *  

def run_script(iface):
   uri = QgsDataSourceUri()
   uri.setConnection("hmlr-landmk-db-psql-2a.ca3udrng5rkp.eu-west-2.rds.amazonaws.com", "5432", "Base_test", 
   "postgres", "********")
   uri.setDataSource("sandbox", "+ default +")

   layer = QgsVectorLayer(uri.uri(), "+ default +", "postgres")
   if not layer.isValid():
       print("Layer %s did not load" %layer.name())  
   QgsProject.instance().addMapLayer(layer)

   run_script()
   
#convert geometry to string
   from shapely import wkt 
   gridDIF['str_geom'] = gridDF.geometry.apply(lambda x: wkt.dumps(x))
   
#pop up box for charge info
oaci_variable = feature.geometry()
QMessageBox.information(None,"check oaci:", str(oaci_variable))```
````

Comment: Welcome SLC. Is there a reason you dont edit the PostGIS layer directly in QGIS?

Comment: i do edit in QGIS but then this change needs to be saved in the database. Currently we make the change in QGIS, save the shapefile then add this to a workbench in FME to create the new geometry as a string which then updates in the database, im trying to cut out the use of FME in this process. Im quite new to all of this so not 100% sure on how i should go about it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Allow me to propose an alternate workflow (provided you have permission to modify the db/table)

**Ensure you can connect to the DB from QGIS**

1. From Layer > Add Layer select Add PostGIS Layers...
2. Click 'New' to create a new connection
3. Enter the appropriate connection information
4. Click the plus sign to create a new Authentication Configuration.
   Give the Configuration a name and enter your db username and password before saving (Basic Auth)
5. Click Test Connection in the new connection popup and confirm you can connect
6. Configure the bottom checkboxes according to your needs (note that saving projects in the db is very handy imo)
7. Click OK to finish creating the connection

**Create a geometry column in the destination table**

PostGIS tables with geometry columns can be rendered/edited directly in the QGIS canvas which will greatly simplify your project. You can use the following to create a geometry column:

```
alter table your_schema.your_table add column if not exists geom geometry(MULTIPOLYGON,4326);
```

*This assumes you plan to store multipolygon geometry type in WGS84, modify to suit your needs*

**Update the new geom column using the existing geom strings**

There are various ways geometrys can be stored as strings in the db. The following will update the geom column assuming the string is in geojson format and stored in a column named string_geom (you can remove the st_multi call if you are not keeping multipolygons):

```
update your_schema.your_table set geom = st_multi(ST_GeomFromGeoJSON(string_geom, 4326));
```

**You can add an index to the geometry column for enhanced query performance:**

```
create index if not exists your_schema_your_table_geom_idx on your_schema.your_table using GIST (geom);
```

**Add the table as a layer in QGIS**

1. Return to Layer > Add Layer > Add PostGIS Layers... and click connect on your db connection
2. Locate and expand the appropriate schema and select the table/geom column. ***Note1**: it is possible to have more than 1 geometry column in a postgis table, so ensure you are adding the geometry column you want. **Note2**: If you see a yellow 'yield' sign next to the schema name it is indicating that your table has no primary key, you can still add the layer - but you probably should go ahead and create a primary key.*
3. Click Add and then Close

**Bombs away!**

Your table should now be visible as a layer in the Layers Panel. You can style/edit/save this layer as if it were a local shapefile and the changes will be persisted to the db upon save.

*Note that this will not maintain the geojson column after geometries are added/updated (only the PostGIS geom column). If that is a requirement, you will need to use another method (I use generated columns for this purpose).*

**You can learn more about PostGIS-QGIS integration [here](https://docs.qgis.org/3.28/en/docs/training_manual/spatial_databases/spatial_functions.html)**